# HTML wipe transitions

Tags: html, transition

1. I'm trying to perform wipe transitions between different elements on my page (for instance when an image has to replace another image) and I'm looking for a way to do this without using 3rd party libraries or JS. Is there a way to specify the type of transition that I'm looking for (wipe, fade etc).
2. When I want an element to dissapear (imagine selecting a row in a list and having the selected row dissappear), is there a way to animate setting display:none?

Thanks.

Comment: CSS3 offers [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: @EvilEpidemic There doesn't seem to be a way to animate the display property or to set more interesting transitions, such as seen here: http://kudakurage.com/ipad-html5/transitions/fadewave.html

Comment: _“is there a way to animate setting display:none”_ – no, there isn’t. Hiding elements via `display:none` is a “yes/no” thing, and you can not transition between two fixed states, because there is no “in-between”.